# Ui-router infinite loop with .htaccess

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router on my angular app. Everything works fine on my local app with `gulp serve` but on my server when I refresh another page than the home, I got an infinite loop. (ex: /dashboard/my_project/view).

My .htaccess follows the [doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

Here is my **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

**index.js**

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {/* ... */})
      .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard/:projectSlug',
        abstract: true,
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
        resolve: {
          project:  function(projectService, $stateParams, $state) {
            return projectService.getProject($stateParams.projectSlug)
              .then(function(data) {
                return data;
              }, function() {
                return $state.go('error');
              })
            ;
          },
        },
        templateUrl: '/app/components/dashboard/dashboard.html',
      })
      .state('dashboard.view', {
        url: '/view',
        templateProvider: function($http, $stateParams) {
          var projectSlug  = $stateParams.projectSlug;
          var templateName = '/app/projects/' + projectSlug + '/' + projectSlug + '.html';
          return $http
            .get(templateName)
            .then(function(tpl){
              return tpl.data;
            }, function () {
              // template not found
              /* .. */
            })
          ;
        },
        controllerProvider: function($stateParams, HelperService) {
          var controllerName = HelperService.controllerNameByProject($stateParams.projectSlug);
          return controllerName;
        },
      })
      .state('error', {
        url: 'error',
        resolve: {
          errorObj: function() {
            return this.self.error;
          }
        },
        templateUrl: '/app/components/error/error.html',
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  }])
```

Comment: your dashboard template appears to be in the `/app/components/` directory but your other views are calling for `/app/projects/`, is that intentional?

Comment: yes, my app related templates are in `/app/components` and the projects one are in `/app/projects/project_name/ `